# PHP 2D/3D Dynamic Graphing Tool Kit Running on Linux

Tags: php

Does anyone know of a high quality PHP based graph library that I can use I have already looked at pchart (http://pchart.sourceforge.net/). PChart produces pixelated line graphs and does not really have any great 3D graphs? Also I would rather not use Java because of the client side aspect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395541/graphs-charts-in-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147/pie-chart-drawing-in-php http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528263/what-is-the-best-open-source-php-charting-solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/110839/best-graph-and-diagram-toolset-for-php

Comment: Thanks Mike but none of the answers here are any good as it is mainly pchart, Google API and flash. The Google API is the main one mentioned but firstly there is a problem with the value it takes and secondly this is involving a third party with potentially critical data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked through all of the options outlined in the comment posted from Mike and below is my breakdown.

**Charts Packages Found and my Comments:**

http://www.anychart.com/products/anychart/gallery/ - Very expensive $4999 for any use license

http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/ - Flash based but very cool and free
http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/ - This is the second version of above having moved to actionscript 3.0

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/ - Google chart API

http://pchart.sourceforge.net/index.php - pChart I have already used and it is the rendering that is an issue

http://www.advsofteng.com/ - Looked at yesterday and not free

http://www.amcharts.com/ - Flash based charts and not free

http://www.peters1.dk/webtools/php/lagkage.php?sprog=en – Raw PHP using the GD package in Linux but rendering is not good

http://www.fusioncharts.com/Gallery/Category.asp?Column3D – Flash based play 8 or above and not free but very nice

http://www.aditus.nu/jpgraph/ - Java based is free but rendering is no better then pChart

I think we may have a winner! http://ezcomponents.org/docs/api/trunk/Graph_gallery.html

This seems to be an API but a very good one with lots of other stuff they do as well.

Answer (score 0):

- [Open Flash Charts 1](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart/)
- [Open Flash Charts 2](http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/)

Comment: These look great but again this suffers the same issue as jscript in that it is entirely dependent upon the client having it enabled. Also the other issue with these are that they are not image files so if I wanted to download them to add to a document or email I can't.